# Edit MySQL database via HTML-- options?

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, edit

I have a MySQL database (currently using phpmyadmin to manage) that I would like to display as an HTML table and be able to edit the records/columns directly.

What are my options on implementing this? I'm not sure of the terminology I should be seeking out for more information.

I'm already using php/mysql to display the table with checkboxes for deleting multiple records on the fly, but I need to be able to see the full entries on the page and edit individual values.

Also, anyway to 'sort' via an HTML table? Not necessary, just curious.

Comment: have you looked into any grid plug ins? jsGrid, openjs etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great tool for this is `phpMyAdmin`. Programming something like this yourself is difficult.

There might be other "lighter" alternatives. Take a look at this: http://www.google.com/search?q=database+html

Comment: I prefer sqlbuddy to phpMyAdmin http://sqlbuddy.com/. I'm not sure if OP is looking for a mysql administration panel though.

Comment: Simplified your google search URL, A full url exposes a lot of personal information!

Comment: I use phpMyAdmin to do simple SQL stuff, but this is a little trickier as the edits I need to make are based on an individual's availability and not 'updates' etc. I'd love some advice on other ways to harness the power of phpmyadmin. I have a schedule of people, some are 'reserves', I need to change them from 'reserve'one by one into 'position x'-- ideas on this via phpmyadmin?

Comment: Hmm, you might be right. But using a full system like this would make every management much simpler. Auto inc and so on. I'd recommend this.

Comment: "Programming something like this yourself is difficult." If that's the case, then I'll stick w/ manual updates via phpmyadmin and my csv files :) I'm spread too thin to take on a big challenge at the moment.

Comment: Benastan- I am looking to open a page in my browser and edit directly, line by line. I do use phpmyadmin for managing the databases.

Comment: Does it have to be in browser?  Personally, I find it much easier to use a dedicated MySQL GUI tool.  Like SQLYog or the MySQL workbench (others are available).

Comment: Well, it's possible but does require some programming. You could do the sorting with a jQuery plugin. You need to decide if it's worth the time. Personally I do stuff like this in phpmyadmin cause I see no point in reinventing the wheel. If you have more complex things you might consider doing a complete adminpage.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at phpGrid http://phpgrid.com/
It's got all the bells and whistles and is pretty easy to implement.